# Which version of Windows Server matches this OS version of Amazon EC2 Windows instance most?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I need to do some development work on Windows platform. The target production is a Windows Server 2012 in Amazon EC2. Here is some output from running `systeminfo`

[image]

I want to set up a Windows machine locally for development purpose for obvious performance/UI responsive reason. I have checked out MSDN and I cannot find any iso distribution labelled as 'Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard'. It is the closet match I can identify:

[image]

I wonder if anyone know if this Windows server version is good for my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

When you install Windows Server 2012, you have to choose between the Standard and the Datacenter edition; the installation image is exactly the same, hence the single available download on MSDN.

The two editions are technically identical, only the licensing is different (a Datacanter edition, when used as a Hyper-V virtualization host, allows running unlimited Windows virtual machines).